# Issue while setting up nifi cluster

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-nifi

I followed the below tutorial to setup `nifi` `cluster`. Performed everything as mentioned, but receiving the below error.

```
https://pierrevillard.com/2016/08/13/apache-nifi-1-0-0-cluster-setup/
```

But the zookeeper was unable to elect a leader and getting the following error message.

```
2018-04-20 09:27:40,942 INFO [main] org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog Successfully recovered 0 records in 3 milliseconds 2018-04-20 09:27:41,007 INFO [main] org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog@27caa186 checkpointed with 0 Records and 0 Swap Files in 65 milliseconds (Stop-the-world time = 1 milliseconds, Clear Edit Logs time = 7 millis), max Transaction ID -1 2018-04-20 09:27:41,300 INFO [main] o.a.z.server.DatadirCleanupManager autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 30 2018-04-20 09:27:41,300 INFO [main] o.a.z.server.DatadirCleanupManager autopurge.purgeInterval set to 24 2018-04-20 09:27:41,311 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.s.server.ZooKeeperStateServer Starting Embedded ZooKeeper Peer 2018-04-20 09:27:41,319 INFO [PurgeTask] o.a.z.server.DatadirCleanupManager Purge task started. 2018-04-20 09:27:41,343 INFO [PurgeTask] o.a.z.server.DatadirCleanupManager Purge task completed. 2018-04-20 09:27:41,621 INFO [main] o.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController Checking if there is already a Cluster Coordinator Elected... 2018-04-20 09:27:41,907 INFO [main] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl Starting 2018-04-20 09:27:49,882 WARN [main] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager Unable to determine the Elected Leader for role 'Cluster Coordinator' due to org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /nifi/leaders/Cluster Coordinator; assuming no leader has been elected 2018-04-20 09:27:49,885 INFO [Curator-Framework-0] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl backgroundOperationsLoop exiting 2018-04-20 09:27:49,986 INFO [main] o.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController It appears that no Cluster Coordinator has been Elected yet. Registering for Cluster Coordinator Role. 2018-04-20 09:27:49,988 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager CuratorLeaderElectionManager[stopped=true] Registered new Leader Selector for role Cluster Coordinator; this node is an active participant in the election. 2018-04-20 09:27:49,988 INFO [main] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl Starting 2018-04-20 09:27:49,997 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager CuratorLeaderElectionManager[stopped=false] Registered new Leader Selector for role Cluster Coordinator; this node is an active participant in the election. 2018-04-20 09:27:49,997 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager CuratorLeaderElectionManager[stopped=false] started 2018-04-20 09:27:49,997 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.c.h.AbstractHeartbeatMonitor Heartbeat Monitor started 2018-04-20 09:27:58,179 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@76d9fe26{/nifi-api,file:///root/nifi-1.6.0/work/jetty/nifi-web-api-1.6.0.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.6.0.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-api-1.6.0.war} 2018-04-20 09:27:59,657 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=861ms 2018-04-20 09:27:59,834 INFO [main] o.e.j.C./nifi-content-viewer No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath 2018-04-20 09:27:59,840 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@43b41cb9{/nifi-content-viewer,file:///root/nifi-1.6.0/work/jetty/nifi-web-content-viewer-1.6.0.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.6.0.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-content-viewer-1.6.0.war} 2018-04-20 09:27:59,863 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@49825659{/nifi-docs,null,AVAILABLE} 2018-04-20 09:28:00,079 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=69ms 2018-04-20 09:28:00,083 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.ContextHandler./nifi-docs No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath 2018-04-20 09:28:00,171 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2ab0ca04{/nifi-docs,file:///root/nifi-1.6.0/work/jetty/nifi-web-docs-1.6.0.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.6.0.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-docs-1.6.0.war} 2018-04-20 09:28:00,343 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=119ms 2018-04-20 09:28:00,344 INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.ContextHandler./ No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath 2018-04-20 09:28:00,454 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@67e255cf{/,file:///root/nifi-1.6.0/work/jetty/nifi-web-error-1.6.0.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.6.0.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-error-1.6.0.war} 2018-04-20 09:28:00,541 INFO [main] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Started ServerConnector@6d9f624{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{node-1:8080} 2018-04-20 09:28:00,559 INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server Started @98628ms 2018-04-20 09:28:00,599 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Loading Flow... 2018-04-20 09:28:00,688 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.io.socket.SocketListener Now listening for connections from nodes on port 9999 2018-04-20 09:28:00,916 INFO [main] o.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController Successfully synchronized controller with proposed flow 2018-04-20 09:28:01,337 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Connecting Node: node-1:8080 2018-04-20 09:28:07,922 INFO [Curator-Framework-0] o.a.c.f.state.ConnectionStateManager State change: SUSPENDED 2018-04-20 09:28:07,927 INFO [Curator-ConnectionStateManager-0] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager org.apache.nifi.controller.leader.election.CuratorLeaderElectionManager$ElectionListener@188207a7 Connection State changed to SUSPENDED 2018-04-20 09:28:07,930 ERROR [Curator-Framework-0] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl Background operation retry gave up org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:728)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:857)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:809)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:64)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:267)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    2018-04-19 15:56:55,209 ERROR [Curator-Framework-0] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl Background operation retry gave up
    org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: 
    KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at 



    org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:728)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:857)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:809)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:64)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:267)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I set the following properties on all 3 nodes:

```
mkdir ./state
mkdir ./state/zookeeper
echo 1 > ./state/zookeeper/myid (2 & 3 for other nodes)
```

in zookeeper.properties

```
server.1=node-1:2888:3888
server.2=node-2:2888:3888
server.3=node-3:2888:3888
```

in nifi.properties

```
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=true
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=node-1:2181,node-2:2181,node-3:2181
nifi.cluster.protocol.is.secure=false
nifi.cluster.is.node=true
nifi.cluster.node.address=node-1(node-2 & node-3)
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=9999
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.threads=10
nifi.cluster.node.event.history.size=25
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.firewall.file=
nifi.remote.input.host=node-1(node-2 & node-3)
nifi.remote.input.secure=false
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=9998
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true
nifi.remote.input.http.transaction.ttl=30 sec
nifi.web.http.host=node-1(node-2 & node-3)
```

Comment: Are you using embedded zookeeper or external?

Comment: embedded zookeeper.

Comment: Any chance you can post all three nifi.properties files?

Comment: Please check the updated question.

Comment: I doubt this is the issue, but in state-management.xml there is also a spot where the ZK connect string needs to be entered: <property name="Connect String"></property>

Comment: i changed that property <property name="Connect String">node-1:2181,node-2:2181,node-3:2181</property> and the issue remains.

Comment: Ok thanks for trying that, seems like a possible networking issue where something can't be reached, but hard to say.

Comment: Please check the updated log in the question, lets see if you can make anything out of it.

Answer (score 2):

After Bryan's comment, got reminded that I forgot to disable the iptables (I guess I can even open the ports but since this is for my practice I am disabling the iptables) and its working now.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error after disabling iptables. My configuration is similar to what specified above. Any ideas?